# select checkbox with custom styling in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a checkbox as selector in my jQuery. When the checkbox is checked, it is supposed to attr the css class for another div element. 
My problem is that jQuery doesnt react to the :checked paramenter

I got following:

jQuery

```
    $(function () {
        if ($('#tab').is(':checked')) {
            $(".choices").attr({ "visibility": "visible" });
            $(".question1").attr({ "border-bottom-left-radius": "0px" })
        }
        else {
            $(".choices").removeAttr('style');
            $(".question1").removeAttr('style');
        };
```

HTML

```
                    <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="tab" /><span class="label-text">Valgmuligheder</span>
                    </label>
```

what i mean by custom checkbox, is that i used a font for the box instead of the initial styling. However the initial checkbox is just hidden, and is being checked together with the font.

I guess my code fails in my selector, but i just cant seem to get it right.

Comment: Ever heard of event listeners?

Comment: `$('#tab').on('change', function(e) { if (this.checked) { ... } });`

Comment: Is it your completed code?

Comment: should i add to the post that im new to jQuery. Im not completely sure how to use event listeners.

Comment: It is my complete code yes

Comment: @JeppeC please check below given JS, I am not sure about your requirement but check if same one then we can change it as per your need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below JS, but for your login please update it as per your requirement -

```js
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
        if ($('#tab').is(':checked')) {
          alert('hii');
            $(".choices").attr({ "visibility": "visible" });
            $(".question1").attr({ "border-bottom-left-radius": "0px" })
        }
        else {
            $(".choices").removeAttr('style');
            $(".question1").removeAttr('style');
        }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="tab" /><span class="label-text">Valgmuligheder</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you! it works great. Is that an eventlistener? and what does the change(function() exactly mean?

Comment: @JeppeC Happy to hear it works for you, Change function means it will fire on change event like on check the checkbox is a change and uncheck also is a change, for dropdown, checkbox and radio button we use this function

Comment: refer these links for more info on `events` & `handlers` ,https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers ,https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Overview_of_Events_and_Handlers